# Javascript- how to get image width, height from the base64 code

Tags: javascript

I have a base64 img encoded. How can I get the height and the width of it?

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
var i = new Image(); 

i.onload = function(){
 alert( i.width+", "+i.height );
};

i.src = imageData;
```

Comment: `i.height` and `i.width` will be available inside your `i.onload` function, just as you show in the code. What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.write(img.width + ' × ' + img.height);
});

img.src = "<your base64 string>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works...

```js
const imageData = "data:image/png;base64,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";
var i = new Image();

i.onload = function() {
  alert(i.width + ", " + i.height);
};

i.src = imageData;
```